# Symfony2 multihosting

Tags: php, symfony

I have one webhosting with 2 domains. Folder tree is in the image bellow. Where I should put Symfony2 folder? I put them into kozusnikjan.com folder, but it said

> Warning: require(/data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/app/autoload.php on line 9

So where I should put them? Thank you

[image: My folder structure]

I tried it, but it results in an error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: did you run composer update? looks like composer hasn't created it's autloader file

Comment: how to do it? thank you

Comment: In command line go to the root dir of your project (www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/) and then run composer update. If you need more information about composer [click here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: I did, as you said. But if I go to the kozusnikjan.com it wrotes: Warning: require_once(/data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/app.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual') in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/app.php on line 6

Comment: What do you mean please? 
Now it wrotes smt. like this:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message ...

Comment: If you mean the error, I repared it - it was beaucse of int in php.ini... Than I install composer and type  "php composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader"

Comment: So what to do with it? I´m thinking about it for 3 days, I tried almost everything... please, help

Comment: When I said "In your question, please", I meant if you have further information, then please click the ['edit' link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19617695/edit) and put the information in there. Use the formatting tools too, so a prefix of ">" is good for quoting stuff like errors. This makes it easier for new readers: they can just read the improved question, rather than having to wade through lists of appended comments.

Comment: Ok. I´m sorry. I will use the prefix, as you said. Thank you. Do you know, where might be the problem please? Thank you very much